# SQL query to find columns having at least one non null value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am developing a data validation framework where I have this requirement of checking that the table fields should have at least one non-null value i.e they shouldn't be completely empty having all values as null.

For a particular column, I can easily check using

```
select count(distinct column_name) from table_name;
```

If it's greater than 0 I can tell that the column is not empty. I already have a list of columns. So, I can execute this query in the loop for every column but this would mean a lot of requests and it is not the ideal way.

What is the better way of doing this? I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Checking with exists for a non null value is probably faster, but you still need to do it column by column.

Comment: your `count distinct` returning 1 doesn't tell by itself that the value is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not recommend using `count(distinct)` because it incurs overhead for removing duplicate values. You can just use `count()`.

You can construct the query for counts using a query like this:

```
select count(col1) as col1_cnt, count(col2) as col2_cnt, . . .
from t;
```

If you have a list of columns you can do this as dynamic SQL.  Something like this:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

select @sql = concat('select ',
                     string_agg(concat('count(', quotename(s.value), ') as cnt_', s.value),
                      ' from t'
                    )
from string_split(@list) s;

exec sp_executesql(@sql);
```

This might not quite work if your columns have special characters in them, but it illustrates the idea.

Comment: Yes you are right,i dont really need distinct,just count() would do the job

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use `exists` since you aren't really needing a count of anything.

You don't indicate how you want to consume the results of multiple counts, however one thing you could do is use `concat` to return a list of the columns meeting your criteria:

The following sample table has 5 columns, 3 of which have a value on at least 1 row.

```
create table t (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int, col5 int)
insert into t select null,null,null,null,null
insert into t select null,2,null,null,null
insert into t select null,null,null,null,5
insert into t select null,null,null,null,6
insert into t select null,4,null,null,null
insert into t select null,6,7,null,null
```

You can name the result of each case expression and concatenate, only the columns that have a non-null value are included as `concat` ignores nulls returned by the case expressions.

```
select Concat_ws(', ',
    case when exists (select * from t where col1 is not null) then 'col1' end,
    case when exists (select * from t where col2 is not null) then 'col2' end,
    case when exists (select * from t where col3 is not null) then 'col3' end,
    case when exists (select * from t where col4 is not null) then 'col4' end,
    case when exists (select * from t where col5 is not null) then 'col5' end)
```

Result:

> col2, col3, col5

Comment: This could potentially end up doing five full table scans in the case that all five columns are in fact full of nulls

Comment: Yes you're right, of course that's the worst-case scenario. It could also end up only reading a single page of every table, all depending on the data distribution; the count method though is guaranteed to scan every table.

Comment: @stu what if i have close to 80 columns,infact one of my table has close to 80 columns?

Comment: Then you possibly need to look at your table design and normalise the data! However if you're saying you have 80 columns you need to identify as having any non-null values in then you have to write a query that checks each column regardless; doing a count() on each column will do 80 scans guaranteed. with up to 80 columns, I would be looking at writing some dynamic sql to build the query to check for null values for me.

Comment: @Stu yes i understand its a bad table design nonetheless, but we dont really own that table and just have read privileges

Comment: "doing a count() on each column will do 80 scans guaranteed." - not if done at all intelligently. You want one query that does `SELECT COUNT(Col1), COUNT(Col2) ...` etc so that it gets the results for all 80 columns from one table scan. You wouldn't do 80 separate queries. The 80 individual `EXISTS` could work out better if the table is large and all of the columns have a `NOT NULL` value found early - but if you knew the likelihood of finding a `NOT NULL` value up front you probably wouldn't be needing this query.

Comment: yes i am planning to write a query which can do 80 counts at once in one single query instead of firing 80 separate requests.

Comment: That would make the most sense then to build something dynamically. As @MartinSmith says above you'd want to do a single pass, there's going to be a tipping point where it makes more sense to do that than checking each column with exists - I think exists makes sense for fewer columns but if it's as large as you say then a one-off scan and count will almost certainly be better.

Answer (score 1):

I asked [a similar question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/19344/3690) about a decade ago. The best way of doing this in my opinion would meet the following criteria.

- Combine the requests for multiple columns together so they can all be calculated in a single scan.
- If the scan encounters a `not null` value in every column under consideration allow it to exit early without reading the rest of the table/index as reading subsequent rows won't change the result.

This is quite a difficult combination to get in practice.

The following *might* give you the desired behaviour

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 ColumnWithoutNull
FROM YourTable 
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CASE WHEN b IS NOT NULL THEN 'b' END),
                   (CASE WHEN c IS NOT NULL THEN 'c' END)) V(ColumnWithoutNull)
WHERE ColumnWithoutNull IS NOT NULL
OPTION ( HASH GROUP, MAXDOP 1, FAST 1)
```

*If* it gives you a plan like this

[image: Unpivoted]

Hash match usually reads all its build input first meaning that no shortcircuiting of the scan will happen. If the optimiser gives you an operator in "flow distinct" mode it won't do this however and the query execution can potentially stop as soon as `TOP` receives its first two rows signalling that a `NOT NULL` value has been found in both columns and query execution can stop.

But there is no hint to request the mode for hash aggregate so you are dependent on the whims of the optimiser as to whether you will get this in practice. The various hints I have added to the query above are an attempt to point it in that direction however.

Comment: This looks really complex and difficult to implement

Comment: yeah, and you aren't even guaranteed to get the desired plan at the end of it either. Unless you have reason to suspect that there is a high probability that all columns will contain at least 1 not null value I'd just do a count of all columns so it can get results for all of them in one full scan.

Comment: makes sense ,can you please elaborate this statement " I'd just do a count of all columns so it can get results for all of them in one full scan"

Comment: Basically as Gordon's answer. If the result for a column is not 0 then it contains at least one `NOT NULL` value. And the result for each column is the exact number of `NOT NULL` values if needed